# Cannot access object property

Tags: php

Here is the litteral String displayed on front side when making an ajax call request.

```
'{
  "nogescom": "",
  "aa": "",
  "acc": "",
  "fournisseur": "001501",
  "semaineEnt": "",
  "debutPeriodeDep": "",
  "finPeriodeDep": "",
  "codepro": "",
  "statutCde": "",
  "statutBieCde": "",
  "isfromgnx": false,
  "usrcreatemodif": false,
  "nocde": "",
  "debutPeriodeCrea": "",
  "finPeriodeCrea": "",
  "fam": "",
  "sfam": "",
  "ssfam": "",
  "entrepot": "",
  "statutDepart": "",
  "saison": "",
  "portDepart": ""
}'
```

So, this literal String is sent to the back side in `PHP 5.4`

I'm trying to this on Back Side:

```
$json = new Services_JSON();

$criteresRecherche= (object) $json->decode($elements);
var_dump($criteresRecherche->fournisseur);
```

But the var_dump function displays `null`, I don't understand why!

Comment: first step is to var_dump the `$criteresRecherche` var to make sure it returns what you're expecting

Comment: ...and before that the `$elements` var too, to make sure that its contents is really a json string

Comment: we don't know what your "decode" function does. Does it call the regular json_decode() function in the background? Certainly if you use the normal function, your code would work fine. Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fa557fa787e67d8e09b43c58d3d45b986d65a883

Comment: Don't use that function. That PEAR package is 7 years old. Use this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Off topic : PHP 5.4 is end of life since 2015. PHP 5.x and 7.0 will become end of life january 1st. You should consider updating to PHP 7.1 or 7.2. [source](http://php.net/supported-versions.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$json = json_decode($elements);  //without the true parameter`

This will create an stdClass object that you can access like:

```
$json->fournisseur
```

`json_decode` is supported from php version 5.4 and above so it should work for you.

If you want to create an array and not an object just add `true`in the `json_decode()`

`$json = json_decode($elements,true);`

and of course you access it like:

```
$json['fournisseur'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final answer :

```
$elements = json_decode($elements);
$criteresRecherche = json_decode($elements->criteres);
```

Comment: seems like the answer was done by pr1nc3 first - perhaps accept their post and delete this one?